# Is there an easy way to generate a random number string in a DTM data element for use as a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, variables, tags, adobe-analytics

I'm new to using DTM and have some third party tags that need unique ID variables.

In GTM there was the functionality to add a random number string but I can't find any documentation to do this in DTM.

Has anyone done this before?

Cheers,

Rosie

Comment: What's the purpose of the unique ID variables? Does adding an ID make the variable value unique to the session? Is it used to control expiration?

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks for you message. Exactly as you say it's to make the variable value unique to the session.

Comment: Hi Rosie - 
There is no native function in DTM for creating unique IDs but you can set a cookie with a session expiration that contains the unique ID. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty straight forward post on generating a [random number string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript).

The thought around that would be to create a Data Element and set the type to custom script and drop in the random number string. Then create a Page Load rule that sets an eVar or sProp to whatever that newly created Data Element is?